# Which is a good Continuous Integration Solution (e.g. CruiseControl.net) hosting provider?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, unfuddle

I have a private .NET (C#) project using Git Repository in Unfuddle.com. I wish to utilize a hosted Continuous Integration tool like CruiseControl.Net. Can anybody recommend a hosted CI solution, that can integrate with Git and is reliable and cost effective?
Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your price range?

Comment: I am testing a trial development infrastructure setup for .NET (C#) using Git and CI (preferably Cruisecontrol.NET or better). I got a trial account@unfuddle, but for commercial, i may opt for repositoryhosting.com starting with about 10$/month. Eager to know how much i need to spend for hosted CI solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [projectlocker.com](https://www.projectlocker.com) but don't know anything about them.

I will say though, that setting up your own CI server is fairly simple and will probably only take you 1 day to setup for your projects.

Comment: Nick, thanks a lot for the answer. Looks like they have CI build for .NET applications too.

Comment: We just relaunched our hosted build offering at ProjectLocker for .NET and Java as well. You can sign up for a free consultation and setup at 
http://go.projectlocker.com/continuous-integration

Answer (score 1):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) works great with C#\Msbuild and is free of charge up to 20 developers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TeamCity looks good too. However, i am looking for a Continous Integration hosting provider at a reasonable cost per month. Any suggestions for the provider and the price?

Answer (score 0):

[fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com) offers a free hosted CI service, but only for Subversion at the moment.